# Why does (atmospheric) pressure have an effect on solubility?

Tags: solubility

The Wikipedia article titled [Solubility table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table) states that

> The table below provides information on the variation of solubility of different substances (mostly inorganic compounds) in water with temperature, at 1 atmosphere pressure.

Why does pressure have an effect of on solubility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from a combination of [Henry's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law) and [Le Châtelier's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier's_principle). Henry's law is
$$p=k_hc$$
where $p$ is the partial pressure of the gas, $k_h$ is the Henry's law constant and $c$ is the concentration of the gas (because liquids and solids are not affected as much as gases, if at all). This means that with a greater pressure comes a greater concentration, and with a lower pressure comes a lesser concentration, and vice versa

Le Châtelier's principle states that if the pressure, concentration, temperature or volume of a system changes, something else will change to compensate and swing the whole thing back into equilibrium. If there is a greater pressure, there will therefore be a grater concentration. A greater concentration means there is a greater solubility.

The [UC Davis Chem Wiki](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Equilibria/Solubilty/Solubility_and_Factors_Affecting_Solubility) (I didn't see that DrMoishe Pippik had linked to it until after I posted this!) is rather helpful - much more helpful than [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility#Pressure), in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure has a strong effect on the solubility of gases, of course, "forcing" them into solution; see http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Equilibria/Solubilty/Solubility_and_Factors_Affecting_Solubility.

But even solution of solids in liquids are affected somewhat by pressure: for example, proteins may be denatured and made less soluble by high pressure, as in ocean deeps. See http://www.desy.de/news/@@news-view?id=4561&lang=eng for information on that.